# How to display date in another language

Tags: node.js, swig-template

I can’t find any documentation about returning the date in another language using Swig’s date filter.

Is there something I missed, do I have to setup a locale in NodeJs like in PHP or is there simply no internationalization with Swig ?

Comment: post some sample code

Comment: `{{ data.timestamp|date(F) }}`

Comment: With PHP, if you set your locale to `fr-FR` the month name will be displayed in french.

I’m trying to find out if a similar system exists in Node so that Swig date filter would return the full month name in the chosen language.

`<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
$date = new Date('2016-01-01');
echo $date->strftime('%B');
?>
// => Janvier
`